# Compact subspace of Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

I have a problem that states:

If $X$ is Hausdorff then for every $x \in X$ and every compact subset $A \subset X$ there exists disjoint neighborhoods $U \ni x, V \supset A$.

So my question is how is this possible if $x \in A \subset X$, So am I assuming this $x \in X \setminus A$? In which case this is open since $A \subset X$ is closed. And by Hausdorfness we can find disjoint neighborhoods then intersect one and union the other to get my disjoint open balls? Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes, the question is missing that $A$ is such that $x\notin A$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio thanks, I can proceed from here I think!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A\subset X$ be compact $x\in X\setminus A$ . (If $A$ is empty then it trivially follows as $\phi$ and $X$ are such $U$ and $V$)

Pick an arbitrary $y\in A$ .

By Hausdorffness there exists $V_{y}$ and $U_{y}$ open and disjoint such that $x\in U_{y}$ and $y\in V_{y}$.

Cover $A$ up by these $V_{y}$'s . That is $\{V_{y}\}_{y\in A}$ covers $A$.

By compactness there exists $V_{y_1},...,V_{y_n}$ such that this is a finite subcover of $A$ . Correspondingly you have $U_{y_1},...,U_{y_n}$ such that $x\in U_{y_i}$ .

Then $V=\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}V_{y_{i}}$ and $U=\displaystyle\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}U_{y_{i}}$ are disjoint open sets such that $A\subset V$ and $x\in U$.

Comment: thanks, along the lines of what I was trying to do !

Comment: For compactness, doesn't it make more sense to say there exists some finite subset $B \subset A$ such that $A \subset \bigcup_{a \in B}V_a$ since they might not be indexed from $1$ to $n$?

Comment: It does not make any difference. If $B\subset A$ is finite then $B$ consists of some points right? . So either you do not introduce any notation for elements in $B$ or just call the elements in $B=\{y_{1},...,y_{n}\}$.

Comment: I see, I was just told once upon a time that when arguing a compactness case, we cannot assume the sub cover is indexed by $1,2,...,n$.  It may be indexed by $1,4,7,10$

Comment: Ah. I see the confusion . For example if I have a collection(of points/sets or whatever) like $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$. Then I cannot( should not morally) denote a subcollection by $U_{1},...,U_{n}$ because $1,2...$ these might not be in $A$. However you can write as $U_{\alpha_{1}},...,U_{\alpha_{n}}$ because $\alpha_{j}$ should mean to any reader that $\alpha_{j}$ must be one of the elements of $A$. Or you can alternatively just mention that $\alpha_{j}$'s $\in A$.

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is how is this possible if $x \in A \subset X$

Well, it is not possible in such case. And so there's a missing assumption: $x\not\in A$.

> And by Hausdorfness we can find disjoint neighborhoods then intersect one and union the other to get my disjoint open balls?  Am I on the right track?

Almost there. You need one more step: remember that an (infinite) intersection of open subsets does not have to be open. You need to reduce this situation to finite case. And you can do that, since $A$ is compact: you can take a finite subfamily that covers whole $A$, and intersect corresponding neighbourhoods of $x$.